# -23690 code when trying to upload to Apple App Store?

Tags: ios, xcode

[Screencap of error window.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6h26K.png)

I'm trying to upload an archive to the app store in Xcode, and this is what's spit back at me. I'm not having any luck finding out what it's supposed to mean. Every other error I've encountered had at least  *some* detail to go off of, but this time it just displays the error code number.

Comment: Have you tried again or does it do this every time? Try increasing the build number?

Comment: in this moment I have the same issue..

Answer (score 2):

I believe I had a similar problem to this and solved it by uploading using the `Application Loader` opposed to the `Organizer`.

1. First export your archive.
2. Then open application loader in Xcode >
   Open Developer Tools > Application Loader
3. Then click "Deliver Your App" and add your exported archive.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried -

- Increasing the build number
- Adding the relevant permissions to you Info.plist (camera permissions, 
  location etc)
- Added the correct assets for app icons
- Check your provisioning profile settings and make sure they are correct.

I've had more luck using Application Loader for submission so you might want to try that.

Hope this helps.